# SSIS Package Runs in BIDS but fails with an Architecture Mismatch in SQL Agent

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc, openedge, progress-db

I have an SSIS package that uses an ODBC connection to a Progress database as a source using a 32-bit ODBC driver.  This package runs perfectly within the confines of BIDS.  However, when I run it using the SQL Agent, it fails with the error:

> The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver
>   and Application.

I know that this is probably a result of it wanting a 64-bit ODBC driver for that connection, but I can't seem to get the 64-bit driver to work correctly within BIDS.  Is there a trick that would allow me to use the 32-bit driver within SQL Agent and move on with my life?

Answer (score 3):

I found my answer.  Under the Execution Options in the Job Step Properties there is a checkbox at the very bottom --- "Use 32-bit Runtime."  Simple enough!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I did even know that was there. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

BIDS = your local box, 32 bits
SQL Agent = your server, 64 bits

is that right?

If yes, you will really need the correct driver.
This is from BOL:

> Be sure to note that if you develop a package in a 32-bit environment
>   and want to run the package in a 64-bit environment, the connection
>   managers need to be 64-bit compliant. Some connection managers such as
>   Excel work in a 32-bit environment only.

Answer (score 0):

Yuo can call 32bit DTEXEC directly with CmdExec. Point at 32bit DTEXEC.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\dtexec.exe